# how to forward an email after adding text with outlook/python?

Tags: python, email, outlook, message, forward

I'm trying to open an email add some text to it and forward it using python windows extensions.

This is what I have:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI") 

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders('SUBFOLDER')
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
NewMsg = message.Forward
NewMsg.To = "email@email.com" #I want to forward it to this address
```

here is what I get when I try to do that last line:

```
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'To'
```

I would like to know how to open that message, add my own text, and then forward it somewhere else? I'd prefer if I have the option of having it display the message in outlook before sending it.

Comment: Try to replace `message.Forward` with `message.Forward()`.

Comment: Now I have another problem! When I copy something to the front of the email doing this: NewMsg.Body = "New Text"+NewMsg.Body, it breaks all the hyperlinks in the original message and removes the original formatting. Is there anyway I could keep the original formatting and add new text?

Comment: I think this is a part of another question on SO :)

Comment: ok, Thanks for your help. I asked the new question.